# imputation of NA on financial ratios

Tags: r, missing-data

I'm a student doing a data science report on finance. I need to impute NA on some financial ratios. For example, ROAE. I have negative values and positive values. There are also NA, where they are defined in this way " when the denominator is negative, the results return NA". How I can fill these NA? Also there are financial ratios that are only positive values and NA, for example P/E ratio. Here NA are defined as follow: " when the denominator is negative, the results return NA". But in this case seems that all negative values are replaced by NA. So, my question is how I can fill NA for the first example and for the second? I tried with a `MissForest()`, but I don't know if it works well.
I think that most NAs are negative values, so maybe the solution is to randomly impute negative values that are appropriate to NA, but I don’t know how I can do it.
Maybe there is a way to limit `MissForest()` to impute only negative values...

Comment: It may be useful to explain what is the denominator and why it can be negative. Imputing NAs when they are generated by some deterministic mechanisms may not be a meaningful way to proceed.

Comment: Do you have access to the numerator and denominator of the ratios? Or just the ratios? It would be a lot more productive to get access to the components of the ratios and recreate the ratios yourself than to try to impute the ratios. The body producing the data obviously thought ratios with negative denominators were invalid, so why do think you can just replace them with an imputed value?

Comment: According to Wayne Gretsky, you miss 100% of the shots you don't take, so impute 100%. Tongue in cheek, I hope that illustrates why an analysis of 0 denominator ratio actually is not an imputation problem, but a sampling problem.

Comment: Thanks Noah, i ve access also at absolute financial values, but also inside these there are NA (a lots). So, i think that the NAs inside ratios are divided in "true"NA (no info) and NA generated by the negative denominator.